# Remove whitespace from text while preserving newlines

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to sanitize poetry text, below is the sample: (used `code` tag to better see hidden characters):

`მეორდება ისტორია,

 დღევანდელს ჰგავს გარდასული, 
 რახან ბევრი გვიცხოვრია, 
 ნუთუ დგება დასსარული?!`

არა! არ თქვა დავბერდითო, 
 ნუ მაჯერებ, რაც არ მჯერა, 
 არ მწამს სიტყვა ავბედითი, 
 რომ ჩამძახონ ათასჯერაც!

I tried with:

```
function sanitize(txt)
{
    txt = txt.replace(/\s+\n/g, "\n");
    return txt;
}
```

It works but also removes new lines between paragraphs. I just want to remove extra white space from the end and sometimes from the start from each line and leave new lines as much as presented

I know it'd be easy to solve but I'm stuck

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s` matches spaces including line breaks.

```
txt.replace(/^ +| +$/gm, "");
```

This removes one or more horizontal spaces (except tabs) which are present at the start or at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[ ]+|[ ]+$
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/48

```
var re = /^[ ]+|[ ]+$/igm;
var str = 'მეორდება ისტორია,\nდღევანდელს ჰგავს გარდასული, რახან ბევრი გვიცხოვრია, ნუთუ დგება დასსარული?! \n\n არა! არ თქვა დავბერდითო, ნუ მაჯერებ, რაც არ მჯერა, არ მწამს სიტყვა ავბედითი, რომ ჩამძახონ ათასჯერაც! ';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```